# running nohup osascript do shell - result in errors

Tags: bash, macos, nohup, osascript

I'm running a command file which enables me to double-click. File name: `Documents.command` runs a process in the background without having a terminal window open; therefore, I'm using `& pkill -f -a Terminal` to close the *terminal app*.

It was working before, but now my Documents folder opens more than once. Meaning, if I close the folder within 10 seconds, it opens up again.

script code:

```
#!/bin/sh

open ~/Documents

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )" 
nohup osascript -e 'do shell script "'"$DIR"'/Documents.command"' & pkill -f -a Terminal
```

The log file I've recorded displays the following errors:

```
ScriptingAdditions/Digital Hub Scripting.osax" cannot be used with the current OS because it has no OSAXHandlers entry in its Info.plist.
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/System/Library/ScriptingAdditions/StandardAdditions.osax" cannot be used with the current OS because it has no OSAXHandlers entry in its Info.plist.
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/Adobe Unit Types.osax" cannot be used with the current OS because it has no OSAXHandlers entry in its Info.plist.
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/pC Finder Injector.osax" cannot be used with the current OS because it has no OSAXHandlers entry in its Info.plist.
osascript: OpenScripting.framework - scripting addition "/Library/ScriptingAdditions/SIMBL.osax" cannot be used with the current OS because it has no OSAXHandlers entry in its Info.plist.
syntax error -1757.  Couldn't get error text because of error -1757.
```

What seems to be the problem here?

Comment: Your description is confusing. Why would the folder open again, and how is that related to 10 seconds? How is the log file created? You haven't mentioned what the background process does. Better not to use `-f` with `pkill`, because you're only matching the process _name_, not the full command line.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that `Do shell script` works for only *scripts* (which I thought *.command* files would be consider a script, apparently not.)

When using .command files in a osascript, I had to do the following for no error(s).

```
nohup osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "'"$DIR"'/Documents.command"'
```

using the `tell application` trigger with `Terminal` worked!

Comment: `do shell script` passes its argument to `/bin/sh -c`, so as long as the `.command` file is executable and has a valid shebang line and the filename is quoted, if necessary, it _should_ work. Try `echo 'echo hi' > t.command; chmod +x t.command; osascript -e 'do shell script "./t.command"'`. `tell application "Terminal" to do script` launches Terminal and runs the script in a window  (although without activating it).